# Format 1k to 1000.00 or 1m to 1,000,000.00 in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In MS Excel 2010, I would like to format a cell that contains **"1k"** to show as **"one thousand number format"** and show **"1m"** as **"one million number format"**

(1k = $1000.00) or (1m = $1.000,000.00) so the number 250k will be displayed in the cell as $250,000.00

**Part 2.**
Say I have a Workbook the sheets have the above information in columns with a `HEADING`. 3 Sheets,
For this will call it cost_of_goods 1/ 2/ 3/,

> `Sheet 1`, has a column, `cog2001` heading at `M1` down with the above
>   example `1k` or `1m`.
>
> `Sheet 2`, has a column, `cog2002` heading at `M1` down with the above
>   example `1k` or `1m`.
>
> `Sheet 3`, in column `A1` `=T('cog2001'!M1)` `B1` `=T('cog2002'!M1)`
>
> `Sheet 3`, has the totals from the columns, each column has 1000+
>   entry's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of a cell is the string "1k", then you cannot display "$1000.00" in the same cell.

You have to show the "$1000.00" in a different cell.

If you are OK on showing the result on another cell, then, assuming that your input is in A1, you can use the formula below:

=TEXT(  IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="k",VALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))*1000,IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="m",VALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))*10^6,A1)), "#,##0.00")

Comment: True - forgot to mention that in my answer.

Comment: Thought I'd add a slight variation to your formula:  `=TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))*IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="k",1000,IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="m",10^6,A1)), "#,##0.00")` - would be no faster, but slightly shorter formula.

Comment: @Darren: the shorter formula would not work in the case where the user types a number (without "k" and without "m").

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in Excel showing what the letter stands for.

In my example I have placed **k** in `C1` and **1000** in `D1`, **m** in `C2` and **1000000** in `D2` (so my conversion tables covers the range `C1:D2`)
Enter 250k or 1k or 250m in cell `A1`.

This formula will convert the figure:
`=LEFT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-1)*VLOOKUP(RIGHT($A$1,1),$C$1:$D$2,2,FALSE)`

Then just format the cell as currency.

**Edit:**
As @gavi pointed out - the formula needs to go in a different cell.
You could use a VBA solution (the code will convert if placed in cells A1:A10 - there's no error trapping, so easy to break it).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyNum As Double
    Dim MyMultiplier As Double

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1:$A$10")) Is Nothing Then
        MyNum = Left(Target, Len(Target) - 1)

        Select Case Right(Target, 1)
            Case "k"
                MyMultiplier = 1000
            Case "m"
                MyMultiplier = 1000000
        End Select
        Target = MyNum * MyMultiplier
        Target.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: and gavi thanks, that seems like what I need i'll get back to you. Thanks for the fast reply everyone.